# MacVim -- how to make Ctrl+A go to beginning of line, Ctrl+E to the end of the line

Tags: macos, keyboard, macvim

I'm trying to switch to MacVim as my main editor, and I'm liking it so far, except for one issue:

I got really used to the Mac shortcuts <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to go to the beginning of a line, and <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> to go to the end of a line.

However, these two don't work in MacVim (<kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> does something weird -- it seems to increase the last number in a line by 1 or something, and <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> seems to scroll down the screen by one line).

Any way to make these two shortcuts go to the beginning of a line / end of a line respectively instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to `.vimrc` or `.gvimrc`:

```
:" Map Ctrl-A -> Start of line, Ctrl-E -> End of line
:map <C-a> <Home>
:map <C-e> <End>
```

Comment: I don't use mac, but you might want to use noremap instead of map, in case you ever want to map <Home> or <End> somewhere else.  In addition, you might want to use imap (or inoremap) in addition so that the hotkeys work in insert mode.

Answer (score 2):

Those are actually emacs shortcuts that OSX is using, so you're asking how to emulate emacs key bindings in vim, which is a little unintuitive.

Id highly suggest getting used to either ^ to go to the beginning of a line, or I (shift-i) to go to the beginning of the line and switch to insert mode.

Comment: For the record, they aren't Emacs shortcuts, they're much older and are present throughout the vast majority of unix systems, basically every terminal has them.