# vi shortcuts on bash on mac not working e.g. CTRL + E, CTRL + A

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, vi

I have used vi as my main text editor for years now on Linux (and a few years back Mac too) and on my brand new Mac (running 10.8.4) I find when trying to edit a file using vi in Terminal I can not use the standard vi shortcuts e.g. using 'CTRL + E' to navigate to the end of a line. Instead the shortcut is set to the vim shortcut which is '$' to navigate to the end of a line. I a using bash. How can I get the standard vi shortcuts?

Comment: vi in osx **is** vim. `:h` and check help file. although check this out http://www.howtogeek.com/166616/how-to-use-vim-style-keyboard-shortcuts-for-os-x-tab-navigation/

Comment: Are you looking for ^A/^E to work in bash (to navigate in the command line) or inside vi/vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set -o vi
```

Add that to your ~/.bashrc

---

If you meant to write "I cannot use the standard **bash** shortcuts Ctrl-E and Ctrl-A in vim", then add these lines to your ~/.vimrc

```
map <C-E> $
map <C-A> 0|
```

If you want these to also work in <strike>input</strike> insert mode, you also need

```
map! <C-E> <esc>A
map! <C-A> <esc>0i
```

These maps for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> send you to the left margin. If you want to go to the first non-space character

```
map <C-A> ^
map! <C-A> <esc>I
```

Comment: This will enable vi mode in bash, not in vim

Comment: that's how I interpreted the question, but re-reading I guess you're right.

Comment: The answer from this post seeemd to do the trick. Thanks for the very fast responses. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49749/macvim-how-to-make-ctrla-go-to-beginning-of-line-ctrle-to-the-end-of-the-l

Answer (score 5):

Ctrl-a for beginning of line and Ctrl-E for end of line are Emacs shortcuts, not vi. As such, they will not work in vi.

Comment: Having used vi for years on linux I never realised that these shortcuts are from emacs. I have always used vi and any linux machine I work on has had these shortcuts so I guess they have always been specially enabled without having realised these were not from vi. Thanks for pointing this out.